# Getting my head around string manipulation

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I've been working on an ExcelDNA/C# add in for a while, and I'm at the final hurdle.

I can get a selection address, and I first of all need to check if the rows in that selection are simply two, e.g. in Excel they would be 8+9, two rows next to each other or any two consecutive numbers.

I then need to check that there are more than two columns, etc C to J (more than two spaces in the alphabet).

This all needs to be done from a string like this: Sheet1!$C$8:$J$9

What I am trying to do, is split a selection like this, which returns the above string, into two strings, in the case of the example, the desired end result would be

***Sheet1!$C$8:$J$8 + Sheet1!$C$9:$J$9*** in two different strings, perhaps I need more coffee, but if anyone has a less trashy way of doing this than I plan, I would be forever in your debt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a reference to the `Range` object? If so, `range.Rows.Count == 2` will tell you if there are two rows, and `range.Columns.Count > 2` will tell you if there are more than two columns.

Then, to get the addresses of the two rows independently you can do something like:-

```
var address1 = range.Rows[1].Address(external:true);
var address2 = range.Rows[2].Address(external:true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a reference to a Range object, I'm getting the selection using the following: //Get a reference to the currently selected range on Excel
                ExcelReference selection = (ExcelReference)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfSelection);
                strSelectionAddress = (string)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfReftext, selection, true);

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to sum the cells, I'm just trying to split the two 'rows' of the selection up into seperate strings for a different use.

Comment: I'll edit my answer accordingly. Regarding the Range object - I don't have ExcelDNA handy right now, but is it not possible to construct a Range object given the address?

Comment: I could do this, but this particular code is part of an elaborate 'if' statement, I need a way of looking at the original string, and being able to recognise that the selection is in this format, your answer solves my second half of the problem though! So for that I am grateful

Comment: I think, in general, if you convert your string address to a range object at the earliest opportunity and, from that point on, work with the range object exclusively, things will be a lot easier. You won't have to do any kind of string address parsing/manipulation at all.

Comment: I've done what you recommended and it seems to work a treat, much appreciated mate!

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is running from a macro called from a CommandBar or Ribbon event handler.
On that case you might as well use the COM Automation interface from the start, and never bother the the C API (XlCall and ExcelReference).

To get the current selection you'd just say

```
Application xlApp = (Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
Range selectedRange = xlApp.Selection as Range;
if (selectedRange != null)
{ .... do you further checking here ...}
```

The C API stuff is a bit more important if you are making user-defined functions or you want high-performance data transfers. But for regular macros the COM API is easier.